# Any idea why no alert is shown when the form is submitted empty?

Tags: javascript

Hello guys trying to make form check but the very basic thing I am doing with javascript is not working any ideas what I am doing wrong?

html:

```
<form onsubmit= "return formCheck();" method="POST" action="check.php"  >
name: <input type="text" name="name" onchange="valid_name.checked = true;">
<input  type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="valid_name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function formCheck() {
    if(this.name.value == ""){
        alert("You forgot to enter your name");
        this.name.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Lawwf/rRNBy/

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are some things wrong with the fiddle:

- No quotes around `return formCheck();` -- although the code given here has them.
- Your JS code is configured to be executed on load, which makes `formCheck` inaccessible to the global context (the setting needs to be changed to "no wrap").

And something wrong with the code:

- Inside your event handler `this` is the `window` object, not the form. Window already has a  `name` property, which conflicts with what you are trying to do. Instead of working this way consider getting hold of the element with DOM searching methods such as `getElementById`, `querySelectorAll` etc.

**[Updated working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dTc63/)**:

```
function formCheck() {
    var el = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=name]")[0];
    if(el.value == ""){
        alert("Je bent vergeten je naam in te vullen");
        el.focus();
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amongst a lot of other things:

1. Using "this" outside an object context will throw an error.
2. You're missing a return in case of no error.
3. In your jsFiddle you missed to quote the event hand

ler strings

Try this:

```
...
<form onsubmit="return formCheck(this);" method="POST" action="check.php"  >
...
```

and then:

```
function formCheck(myForm) {
    if(myForm.name.value == ""){
        alert("You forgot to enter your name");
        myForm.name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onSubmit= "formCheck()" type="POST" action="#" >
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name_input" onBlur="formCheck()">
    <input  type="checkbox" id="valid_name" name="valid_name" disabled>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

```
function formCheck() {
  var val = document.getElementById('name_input').value;
    if(val!='')
      document.getElementById('valid_name').checked = true; 
    else      
      alert('Looks like you forgot your name!');        
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dTc63/1/

*(Just hit run again to try it the other way. POST doesn't work like normal in jsfiddle.)*

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the *this* keyword to the formCheck function.
html:

```
<form onsubmit= "return formCheck(this);" method="POST" action="check.php"  >
name: <input type="text" name="name" onchange="valid_name.checked = true;">
<input  type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="valid_name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function formCheck(frm) {
    if(frm.name.value == ""){
        alert("You forgot to enter your name");
        frm.name.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've checked it. It works unless you've disabled your browser's javascript functionality.